# How to do infinite number of nested dropdown lists in Angular with Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, nested

In my application, i allow infinite number of category levels. For this am using only one table in database  :

```
Category(id, name, #id_parente)
```

In the front, i want to have a form allowing me to choose categories of every level starting from the first level (categories with no parent). When choosing a category, all lower lists should disappear and a new dropdown list of its subcategories should appear if it has subactegories.

Right now, I am able to show the cascading dropdown lists to the last one but  when the last one gets shown the others get random values.

I know this can be done with  [Angular reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) but i do not know exactly how to do it. I found similar issues but all theses issues have constant number of dropdown lists.

This is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
<h1>Profile Form</h1> 
<fieldset formArrayName="items">    
<div class="form-group row"
     *ngFor="let item of profileForm.get('items').controls.reverse(); let i=index"
     [formGroup]="item">
   <h6 >Catégories {{ i }}  </h6>   
  <select  formControlName="si" (change)="onChange($event.target.value, i)" >
       <option *ngFor="let select of findCategoryByParent(profileForm.controls['items']?.value[i]?.si)"  [value]= "select.id">{{select.nom}}</option> 
    </select>  
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule,   FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
 import { NgSelectModule, NgOption } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

 @Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {


readonly cats = [{id : 1, nom: 'Hardware',  parente : 0}, 
               {id : 2, nom: 'Software', parente : 0 }, 
               {id : 3, nom: 'Printer', parente : 1 }, 
               {id : 4, nom: 'MsOffice', parente : 2 }, 
               {id : 5, nom: 'Photoshop', parente : 2 }, 
               {id : 6, nom: 'PC', parente : 1 }, 
               {id : 7, nom: 'Charger', parente : 6 }, 
               {id : 8, nom: 'Corrupted charger', parente : 7 }, 
               {id : 9, nom: 'Excel', parente : 4 }];



  public profileForm: FormGroup;


  public saveProfileForm() {

   console.log(this.profileForm.value);
    }

     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.profileForm = this.fb.group({ 
     items: this.fb.array(
      [this.buildItem(0, 0)]),
  });
 }


buildItem(val: number, i : number) { 
    return  this.fb.group({
      "si": [""] 
    })
    }


    onChange(newValue, i) { 
      console.log(newValue);
     if (typeof this.findCategoryByParent(newValue)  !== 'undefined' &&      this.findCategoryByParent(newValue) .length > 0){ 
   (this.profileForm.get('items') as      FormArray).push(this.buildItem(newValue, i));       
    }
 } 

 findCategoryByParent(parente){ 
    var result = [];

   for(var i = 0;i<this.cats.length;i++) { 
    if(this.cats[i].parente == parente){
      result.push(this.cats[i]); 
   } 
   }

    return result;

   }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need create a "recursive" component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-select',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="items.length>=1">
    <select #select [ngModel]="value" (change)="change(select)">
      <option *ngFor="let select of items" [value]="select.id">{{select.nom}}</option>
    </select>  
    <div *ngIf="value">
      <custom-select [cats]="cats" [parente]="value" (changed)="changeEnd($event)"></custom-select>
    </div>
  </div>
`,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() cats: any[]
  @Input() parente:number;

  @Output() changed=new EventEmitter<number>();
  value;
  get items()
  {
    return this.cats.filter(x=>x.parente==this.parente)
  }
  change(value)
  {
    this.value=value.value;
    if (!this.cats.filter(x=>x.parente==value.value).length)
    {
       this.changed.emit(value.value);
    }
  }

  changeEnd(value)
  {
       this.changed.emit(value);
  }
}
```

And you app-component like

```
<custom-select [cats]="cats" [parente]="0" (changed)="changed($event)"></custom-select>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzswmn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

**Updated**
How clean the under select?
Well use a variable "yet" and a setTimeOut to clean, the code becames like

```
//in the template 
<div *ngIf="items.length>=1">
    .....
    <!-- the condition is "value && yet -->
    <div *ngIf="value && yet">
      <custom-select [cats]="cats" [parente]="value" (changed)="changeEnd($event)"></custom-select>
    </div>
</div>
//In the code
change(value) {
    this.yet = false; //At first this.yet=false. This clean the "under" selected
    //Use a setTimeOut
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.value = value.value;
      this.yet=true;
      if (!this.cats.filter(x => x.parente == value.value).length) {
        this.changed.emit(value.value);
      }

    })
  }
```

the new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5equt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you @Eliso and sorry for replying late. I tried to run your code but i got error saying `this.cats is undefined`. Am using `angular 7 ` and `cli 7.0.5`.  I could not run it also at **stackblitz**, their browser keeps loading page foreever without executing code.

Comment: It works fine now (sorry, i was missing the hello component). Lot of thanks,  you solved it. I marked the answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: There's a problem with the code: not clear all the seelct when you choose. e.g if you select Hardware--PC--Charger-Corrupter charger and the select Software not clean the select. I update the answer to clean these. (see the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5equt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Yeah, i saw that. Thank you.

Comment: Now, i have another problem : i replaced the constant values (the `cats` array) with a dynamic one from a service, but i need to refresh th browser many times to get it working.Why can not it get data from the first time ?

Comment: @GB11, if you subscribe in ngOnInit to a service and eauls in subscribe the code must be work

Comment: @Eliso, i am getting the list of categories in  `ngOnInit() ` of the parent component then i pass it to the child (`HelloComponent`)

Comment: I update the stablitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5equt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts using a service (I simulated an http.get using of and delay) I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you @Eliso. I think it is another issue related to slow loading from backend(Springboot rest backend).

Comment: Anyway try declare cats:any[]=[] in your app.component.ts to Angular not throw an error of "cats are undefined"

Comment: Ok, i will. Thank you